# Declaration Expected error in react js when I'm making a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There is no error in importing the function but there is an error when I'm returning something from my function here is the code:

```
import "./CallPage.scss"
const CallPage = () => {
  return{
   <h1>CallPage</h1>
   }
   }

export default CallPage;
```

and when I'm removing the return  statement another error occurs

error when I'm adding return
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jOdt.jpg)

and when I'm removing return a very big error occurs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF3eR.jpg)

I am Very Confused please help.

Comment: `return{
   <h1>` is invalid syntax. JSX can't come inside an object literal

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses instead of curly braces. return(...your code) instead of return{...your code}

Comment: Thanks You didn't Know What you did Now I can Work on my project. may you do not get any errors in the future God bless you. thanks again.